# Unable to append data to a worksheet in an excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl

How can I append data to my existing worksheet using openpyxl? I've created a scraper in python which is able to grab titles and links from a webpage. I wish to write them in an excel file using openpyxl. However, my scraper neither writes those newly populated data in the excel file nor throws an error? Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance to take a look into it.

Here is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("scraper.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

res = requests.get("https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".mv"):
    name = item.select("a")[0].text
    link = item.select("a")[0]['href']
    ws.append([name,link])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modifications are still in the memory. Add [`wb.save("new file.xlsx")`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file) at the end of the code.

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks @cpc for the solution.